# Best practice for monitoring rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, monitoring

Could you advice gems and best practices to monitoring rails application in production mode?
I want to create a few admin-pages at my application, where I can view production.log and errors. Is it good practice, maybe there are any gems for this?

Answer (score 2):

The following libraries/services are just a few administrative and monitoring tools for use in production environments:

1. [ActiveAdmin](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin) and [RailsAdmin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) are Rails engines mounted within your application for constructing admin interfaces to manage data.
2. [ExceptionNotifier](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification) sends you emails when errors occur that include a backtrace. It offers some configuration options so you can send additional information as well.

   Similar in purpose to ExceptionNotifier, Honeybadger, Airbrake, Rollbar, BugSnag, Sentry, Exceptiontrap, and Raygun are just a few monitoring services that offer a web interface for viewing application errors.
3. [Browserlog](https://github.com/dieb/browserlog) appears to be a Rails engine that allows you to view Rails logs via the web. I've never actually used this one.
4. NewRelic offers performance metrics and analytics.

Don't forget to authenticate your administrative interfaces in production environments!

Comment: Don't forget a process monitor, too, such as Monit or God. Great list!